# python can't make sense of c++ string sent over winsock

Tags: python, c++, xml, string, sockets

Goal:

I am writing a socket server/client program (c++ is the server, python is the client) to send xml strings that carry data. My goal is to be able to receive an xml message from c++ in Python via socket.

**Method**

VS2013 pro
Python 2.7.2 via Vizard 4.1

1) socket communication is created just fine, no problems. I can send/receive stuff

2) after communications are initialized, c++ begins creating xml objects using Cmarkup

3) c++ converts the xml object to std::string type

4) c++ sends the std::string over the stream to Python

**Problem:**

The "string" received in python from C++ is interpreted as garbage symbols (not trying to offend, someone may have strong feelings for them, I do not ;) that look like symbols you'd see in notepad if you opened a binary file. This is not surprising, since data sent over the stream is binary.

What I cannot figure out is how to get Python to make sense of the stream.

**Failed Attempts to fix:**

1) made sure that VS2013 project uses Unicode characters

2) tried converting stream to python string and decoding it string.decode()

3) tried using Unicode()

4) also tried using binascii() methods to get something useful, small improvement but still not the same characters I sent from c++

If anyone can lend some insight on why this is happening I'd be most grateful. I have read several forums about the way data is sent over sockets, but this aspect of encoding and decoding is still spam-mackerel-casserole to my mind.

Here's the server code that creates xml, converts to string, then sends

```
        MCD_CSTR rootname("ROOT");//initializes name for root node
        MCD_CSTR Framename("FRAME");//creates name for child node
        CMarkup xml;//initializes xml object using Cmarkup method
        xml.AddElem(rootname);//create the root node
        xml.IntoElem();//move into it
        xml.AddElem(Framename, MyClient.GetFrameNumber().FrameNumber);//create child node with data from elsewhere, FrameNumber is an int

        CStringA strXML = xml.GetDoc();//convert the xml object to a string using Cmarkup method
        std::string test(strXML);//convert the CstringA to a std::string type
        std::cout << test << '\n';//verify that the xml as a string looks right
        std::cout << typeid(test).name() << '\n';//make sure it is the right type

        iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, (char *)&test, sizeof(test), 0);//send the string to the client
```

Here is the code to receive the xml string in Python:

```
while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)#receive the stream with larger than required buffer
    print(data)#see what is in there
    if not data: break#if no data then stop listening for more
```

Comment: show us a simple example, with the C++ output, and, from the Python side, `print([ord(c) for c in data])`, and we may be able to guess what's happening.  With no such input and output examples, there's no way we can guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `test` is a string, this cannot work:

`iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, (char *)&test, sizeof(test), 0);//send the string`

The `std::string` is not a character array.  It is an object, and all that line does is send nonsensical bytes to the socket.  You want to send the *data*, not the object.

`iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, (char *)test.c_str(), test.length(), 0);//send the string`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write the memory at the location of a std::string and think that's serialization.  Depending on how the C++ library implemented it, std::string is likely to be a structure containing a pointer to the actual character data.  If you transmit the pointer, not only will you fail to send the character data, but the pointer value is meaningless in any other context than the current instance of the program.

Instead, serialize the important contents of the string.  Send the length, then send the character data itself.  Something like this.

```
uint32_t len = test.length();
send(..., &len, sizeof(uint32_t), ...);
send(..., test.c_str(), len, ...);
```

Comment: Even this won't work, since there's no guarantee that `uint32_t` has the same representation at both ends.  (For that matter, there's no guarantee that it even exists on both ends.)  Decide the representation you want, and then format the length to that, and send it.

Comment: Good point.  You want at least a `htonl()` and `ntohl()` pair to handle endianness.  If not uint32_t, any other suggestions for formatting to a 4-byte integer?

Comment: It depends on how you want to format it.  Typically, you can extract the relevant parts directly from the integer (even if it is 36 bit 1's complement, or something else exotic): conversion to unsigned guarantees the equivalent of what the bit pattern would be if it were 2's complement, and either shifting and masking or division and modulo allow extracting parts of it.

Comment: Of course, if the underlying socket protocol is message based, or if the string is structured (he did say XML), he might not need the length at all.